# Making a basic Kotlin SSH app crashes everytime

Tags: android, ssh, kotlin

I am just learning so i am trying to get a very basic SSH query app to compile.
It's supposed to do nothing but an ls.

```
package com.android.myself.sshtestkotlin

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient
import net.schmizz.sshj.common.IOUtils

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val sshConnection = SSHClient()
    sshConnection.connect("localhost")
    sshConnection.authPassword("uid", "password")
    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    val session = sshConnection.startSession()
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    val cmd = session.exec("ls")
    val tempNum = IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString()
    sshConnection.disconnect()
    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, tempNum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}
}
```

I've done a couple of variations with a button to launch the connection etc... but no luck. The moment it calls SSH in any way it crashes.

I tested 2 different virtual devices and two different computers running android studio but no luck.

The make text are just there as debugging to tell me where it breaks but they never show up.

I tried the same with JSCH with the same error.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace, however my gut feeling is probably a permissions issue (`SecurityException`) .. for starters .. You aren't seeing the toasts as that only occurs after you've tried to instantiate a `SSHClient` instance.

Comment: Post `logcat` content for the crash plz.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U-JO4RvfXR-qAc7rlRJPWnugVm3xH9FavomwkLdhjrM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Nicolas Please do not disregard the [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy of StackOverflow. The downvote was very likely probably because this question is off-topic. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.
SSHj past verion 0.9.0 doesn't work with some security. Plus adding 
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2"
    compile "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.57"

solved the logging issues.